# Python : Merging/joining Dataframe after PCA transform results in NAN

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pca

```
import pickle
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
PCA = joblib.load('pcawithstandard.pkl')

with open('collist.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    collist = pickle.load(handle)

for chunk in pd.read_csv('fortest.csv', chunksize = 5):

    _transformed = chunk[collist]
    _transformed = PCA.transform(_transformed)
    _transformed = pd.DataFrame(data=_transformed)

    _tempdata = chunk[['X__1']].join(_transformed)
    print(_tempdata)
```

[image]

I have a few big datasets which has 30k columns and the rows can range from 10k-40k
i'm trying to transform the datasets with a previously fitted PCA i made, and thereafter joining it back with its row label `'X_1'` based on individual dataframe's index.

Since it was a big dataset i decided the use chunksize so that i can limit the amount of memory being used each time.

The joining worked for the first set of chunk, but subsequent chunks just resulted in the right portion of my dataframe to be NAN.

I've checked that the dataframe containing my transformed data, and it does contain values.

instead of joining the transformed data, i tried joining the untransformed data and it seems to work, so I've no idea whats going on.

i suspect that the PCA transform had changed the structure of my dataframe, which resulted it not being able to join properly.

untransformed data has mixture of `int64` and `float64` dtypes columns, and are stored as `object`

transformed data columns are all `float64` and are store as `object` too

untouched chunk data has object `float64` and `int64` and are stored as `object` too

I'm on Python 3.6.4 and My modules version are :

```
numpy (1.16.1)
pandas (0.24.1)
scikit-learn (0.20.2)
```

Appreciate any help and opinions i can get .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you are joining on `index`, where the values remain consistent for the first chunk. But your `_transformed` frame after the first chunk regenerates the index, which is why it cannot find common index values in `chunk[['X__1']]`.

Comment: Maybe try `_transformed = chunk[collist].reset_index()` ?

Comment: you were right! 

I used ```reset_index(drop = True)``` though . 

```reset_index``` adds another column with the old index after resetting it. so drop=True drops that column away.

Comment: post an answer so i can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are performing the `join` on `index` column, you are able to do it successfully for the first chunk.
But for all sebsequent chunks the `PCA` decomposition regenerates the `index`, because of which there is a mismatch between the indices of the original chunk and the decomposed one.

You can do a `reset_index` on each each before decomposing it and you should be able to join it to the original column:

```
_transformed = chunk[collist].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Added `drop=True` for updated answer. :)